# Cómo saber el número de 1 de enero domingos que hay entre 2014 y 2050 en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Este es mi código por el momento (HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ejercicio 1 para practicas de fechas</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
    <!-- Busca todos los 1 de enero que sean domingo de 2014 a 2050. Muestras las fechas por pantalla o en la consola. -->
<body>
    <h2>Aquí puedes consultar todos los 1 de enero que fueron o que serán domingo de 2014 a 2050</h2>
    <button type="button" id="consultar()">Consúltalo aquí</button>



</body>
</html>
```

Y éste el de JavaScript:

```
function consultar(){

    var fecha=new Date(); 
    fecha=01/01/2014; 
    //var dias=["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"];
    var diaSemana=fecha.getDay();

    console.log (diaSemana);


   // for (let i = 2014; i <= 2050; 2014++) {
     //   let anioDomingo=0; 



    //}

}
```

El caso que estoy haciendo eso para ver si me saca al menos el día de la semana del 01/01/2014 pero no me hace nada el programa (para que no entra en la función) y aunque miro el debugger y tal, no le veo el fallo por ningún lado.

Por otro lado, también estoy bloqueado con cómo saber cuántos 1 de enero serán de domingo de 2014 a 2050. Una vez que vea que el getDay(); me funciona entiendo que es hacer un for (como el que tengo comentado), pero no sé cómo aplicar el getDay en un for cuando voy incrementando un año que a su vez va dentro de una fecha. ¿Debería hacer un split día/mes/año?

Y otra cosa... ¿metiéndolo en formato europeo como lo estoy metiendo está bien o debería meter americano?

Muchas gracias, estoy super liado.

Comment: Bienvenido, como referencia para futuras preguntas trata de moderar tu lenguaje, por lo demás buena pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes mas o menos la idea.  Lo que necesitas es ir sumandole un año a la fecha y chequear si es domingo.  Algo asi:

```js
function consultar(){
    var dias=0;
    for (let i = 2014; i <= 2050; i++) {
        var fecha = new Date(i,0,1)
        var diaSemana=fecha.getDay();
        if (diaSemana==0) {
          console.log(fecha);
          dias++;
        }
        
    }
    console.log(dias);

}
```

````html
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Ejercicio 1 para practicas de fechas</title>
    
</head>
    <!-- Busca todos los 1 de enero que sean domingo de 2014 a 2050. Muestras las fechas por pantalla o en la consola. -->
<body>
    <h2>Aquí puedes consultar todos los 1 de enero que fueron o que serán domingo de 2014 a 2050</h2>
    <button type="button" onclick="consultar()">Consúltalo aquí</button>



</body>
</html>```
````